# How to set knp_paginator 'limit per page' inside twig using symfony

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, twig, paginator

I am using *KNP_PAGINATOR* in my Symfony v.5 project running locally. So far, I've been able to get the paginator up and running with no issue. Now, I need to allow the users to be able to choose how many results they want to see per page in their browser. Obviously I already set that value within the controller but how can I change this value depending on user's interaction with the app?

What I was able to do so far: By getting a `{{dump(pagination)}}` inside twig, it shows that there is a parameter called: *numItemsPerPage* which is currently set to 2 (for testing purposes as I do not have many dummy data inside the DB). I can change that like so:

```
    {{ pagination.setParam('numItemsPerPage', 3) }}
```

or even like so:

```
{% do pagination.setParam('numItemsPerPage', 3) %}
```

Both of which will change the dump output to the new value for the said 'numItemsPerPage'. like so:

```
    Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination {#1074 ▼
  -route: "cat_products"
  -params: array:5 [▼
    "direction" => "desc"
    "sort" => "p.id"
    "page" => "1"
    "id" => "1"
    "numItemsPerPage" => 3
  ]
  -pageRange: 5
  -template: "@KnpPaginator/Pagination/twitter_bootstrap_v4_pagination.html.twig"
  -sortableTemplate: "@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sortable_link.html.twig"
  -filtrationTemplate: "@KnpPaginator/Pagination/filtration.html.twig"
  #currentPageNumber: 1
  #numItemsPerPage: 2
  #items: array:2 [▶]
  #totalCount: 5
  #paginatorOptions: array:6 [▶]
  #customParameters: array:3 [▶]
}
```

But it has no effect whatsoever on the actual number of items shown per page!

here is my repository:

```
/**
 * @param string|null $catId
 */
public function getPrdsViaCatId(?string $catId): QueryBuilder
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p') //product
    ->innerJoin('p.category', 'pc') // p=product, pc=product category, ps=product sub-category
    ->innerJoin('p.sub_category', 'ps')
    ->addSelect('pc')
    ->addSelect('ps');
    if ($catId) {
        $qb->andWhere('pc.id = :catId')
            ->andWhere('pc.is_active = :pctrue')
            ->andWhere('ps.is_active = :pstrue')
            ->andWhere('p.is_active = :ptrue')
            ->setParameter('catId', $catId)
            ->setParameter('pctrue', true)
            ->setParameter('pstrue', true)
            ->setParameter('ptrue', true)
        ;
    }
    return $qb
        // ->orderBy('pc.id', 'DESC')
    ;
}
```

The Controller:

```
//start of pagination processing
    $query = $prdRepo->getPrdsViaCatId($id);
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        2/*limit per page*/
    );
```

and finally in twig:

```
<div class="limitPerPage">
                    <select>
                        <option value="10">Show 10 items</option>
                        <option value="20">Show 20 items</option>
                        <option value="30">Show 30 Items</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="sorting mr-auto">
                    <select id="sortSelect">
                          <option value="">Sort results</option>
                        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'ID 0-9', 'p.id', {}, {'direction': 'asc'}) }}
                        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'ID 9-0', 'p.id', {}, {'direction': 'desc'}) }}
                        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Name', 'p.name')|raw }}
                    </select>
                </div>

                {% if pagination %}
                        {% for prd in pagination %}
                           <!-- content goes here -->
                        {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
<div class="pagination">
                        {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
                    </div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how it works. If the user changes the number of items that he will like to see you will have to render your list again. So most simple would be to make a little form that the user can post back to the server.

Comment: @ Frank, thank you for your reply. I will try to use your approach, although I have to say, I was hoping an easier way, something similar to the "direction" method that you can simply insert it in twig and allow users to interact with it! I even tried to look for another pagination bundle, but I gave up on that since none were up to date with Symfony 5.

Comment: clicking on a columnname to change the order or order direction causes a refresh too. It is possible to refresh the  content using AJAX but it won't be simpler.